# Check whether the item is exists in List box or not

Tags: c#, jquery

```
<asp:ListBox ID="list" runat="server" Visible="true" />

if ($('#<%=list.ClientID%> option[value="' + var1 + '"]').length > 0) {
            return false;
        }
```

In my code I am adding items to the list.

Now the code works fine only if the visible property is set to true

Comment: Invisible ASP.NET server controls do not render html.

Comment: if you set Visible to false it never puts the control on the page, so there's nothing to check in that scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invisible ASP.NET server controls do not render html.

Instead of

```
list.Visible = false;
```

use

```
list.Style["display"] = "none";
```

to have control DOM element[s] present client-side.

Answer (score 2):

Asp.net will not create the element if you set the visible property to false.
If you want to hide an element but reachable by javascript (or jquery), don't set the visible proprty. Instead set the display property in the style to 'hidden';

```
 <asp:ListBox ID="list" runat="server" Style="display:hidden;" />
```